# Write chat message to Offic 365 Team User

Tags: asp.net, rest, api, microsoft-teams

Can I write chat messages to teams users with an api(not channels in teams)?
I would like to forward messages from web based email client to users directly into teams chat with an user and not forward the email.

Best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This discusses how to start a 1:1 conversation with a user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/scenarios/bots-personal-conversations#starting-a-11-conversation.

The [Featured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/code-samples#featured) sample apps for Node.js and C# show how to do it.